# How can I get a static value from <select> html tag?

Tags: php, html

I am making an Employment form in php with multiple fields like text, file, select and textarea. I am getting the text and textarea fields in my email when someone submits the form, but without the selected values and files (attachment).

My php code is:

```
if(trim($_POST['FindElance']) || ($_POST['FindGoogle']) || ($_POST['Findsarch']) || ($_POST['FindAdvertisement']) || ($_POST['FindOther']) === '') {
    $FwhereError = 'Please tell where you find us.';
    $FwhereError = true;
} else {
    $Fwhere = trim($_POST['Fwhere']);
}
```

here is the email body variable where it will send value to my email:

```
$body = " 
Where you find us : $Fwhere
";
```

and this is the code for HTML, where I am trying to get validation etc:

```
<div class="clear">How did you find us? : <span class="error">*</span><br></div>

<label class="overyalk" for="areaofinterest"></label>

<select id="wherefrom" class="era-select" name="howufindus" onclick="showhere()">
    <option value="FindElance">Elance</option>
    <option value="FindGoogle">Google</option>
    <option value="Findsarch">Search&nbsp;engin</option>
    <option value="FindAdvertisement">Advertisment</option>
    <option value="FindOther">Other</option>
</select>

</div>
```

I am stuck with it and don't know how it will be done. Here is the online form where I am working

**http://gaabc.us/employment-application-form/**

You also can download my file which I am creating. It is all in one file and it is a Wordpress page inside theme.

**http://gaabc.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/template-employe.zip**

Comment: where are these FindElance, FindGoogle etc ? also where is Fwhere ?

Comment: Actually, there will be two ' names ' to tell php for getting values.One is select tag name and other Option names.I have write php code but dont know how i write with html to get values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough :(

anyway Try this out....

```
$body = "Where you find us : ". $Fwhere;
```

Comment: I am trying to get value from select tag and would like to get it in email.

Comment: For example if someone select " Odesk " from option tag it should be a in email when it will be submitted

Comment: Any kind help please. Here is the form where i am working on my website http://gaabc.us/employment-application-form/

Answer (score 0):

You do not have  `FindElance`, `FindGoogle`, `Fwhere` in your HTML code here.

Name of your Select in form is "**howufindus**".

So you should use it in `$_POST` like this:

```
if(!$_POST['howufindus']) {
    $FwhereError = 'Please tell where you find us.';
    $FwhereError = true;
} else {
    $Fwhere = trim($_POST['howufindus']);
}
```

For attachments you have to use **`$_FILES`**.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this code on your local system as a starting point

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="test" method="post" action="" name="testform">
        <select name="testselect">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="file" name="testfiel" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

this will show you the parameters you get after submitting form, also not to add the uploaded file as extension you need to check it with $_File method.

Comment: Printing `<pre>` tag before even opening html?.. Also, `if($_POST)` is also not a great way for looking if the form has been posted...

Comment: Any kind help Please? Here is the form i am working on my website.
http://gaabc.us/employment-application-form/

Comment: Joran, thanks for comment though that was just a quick code so that Waseem can start...

Comment: Hello SKV.I have updated my question and i added a file link too so you can download this file.

Download link **http://gaabc.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/template-employe.zip**

Answer (score 0):

```
                if(trim($_POST['howufindus']) == '') {
                   $FwhereError = 'Please tell where you find us.';
                   $FwhereError = true;
                } else {
                   echo $Fwhere = trim($_POST['howufindus']);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want...?

```
if(isset($_POST['Fwhere'])) {

$Fwhere = $_POST['Fwhere'];

}
```

Comment: yes i want only one value which is selected by user.Then it will be store in a variable and then i will use that variable in my email body and i can get value. Kindly can you show me with html also?

Comment: **i also tried @Ahamed this one**

`if(isset($_POST['howufindus'])) {
$FwhereError = 'Please tell where you find us.';
$FwhereError = true;
} else {
 
$FindElance = $_POST['FindElance'];
$FindGoogle = $_POST['FindGoogle'];
$Findsarch = $_POST['Findsarch'];
$FindAdvertisement = $_POST['FindAdvertisement'];
$FindOther = $_POST['FindOther'];

}`

Answer (score 0):

As per your html select box, you would not get the selected value by using :

```
<select id="wherefrom" class="era-select" name="howufindus" onclick="showhere()">
    <option value="FindElance">Elance</option>
    <option value="FindGoogle">Google</option>
    <option value="Findsarch">Search&nbsp;engin</option>
    <option value="FindAdvertisement">Advertisment</option>
    <option value="FindOther">Other</option>
</select>

$_POST['FindElance'], $_POST['FindElance'], $_POST['Findsarch']...
```

What you need is :

```
$_POST['howufindus'];
```

And your php would change to :

```
if(trim($_POST['howufindus'])) === '') {
    $FwhereError = 'Please tell where you find us.';
    $FwhereError = true;
} else {
    $Fwhere = trim($_POST['Fwhere']);
}
```

Cheers